# convert a dynamically created table cell to a text box when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically generated table using jquery. I want a cell of the table be converted to a textbox when clicked.

```
$.each(proc_msg, function (i, item) {
  trHTML += "<tr><td>" + item.hq_code + "</td><td id='hq_" + item.hq_name + "'>" + item.hq_name + "</td>";
  trHTML += "<td><a href='#' id='hq_ed_" + item.hq_name+_"' onClick='dataAction(this.id);'>Edit</span></a></td>";
});
$('#tbl_hqlist').append(trHTML);

function dataAction(dataValue){
    var sectionName=dataValue.substr(0,2);
    var hq_zone=dataValue.substr(5);
    var zone_id ="";
    zone_id= zone_id.concat("'#",sectionName, hq_zone,"'");
    var tempHTML ="<input type='text' id='" + zone_id + "' value='" + hq_zone + "' />";
    $(zone_id).html(tempHTML);
```

}

This code is throwing up error where "zone_id" is not defined.

Comment: Your code is a lot more convoluted than it really needs to be. Firstly you have a `_` in your code causing an error. Secondly you can use event delegation to attach the event to the `a`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tjj2tsar/. If you can give an outline of what you're trying to do I can provide a better answer, as I'm sure the current logic can be optimised to not require incremental `id` attributes.

Comment: i have a table with like HQ_Code || HQ_NAME ||  EDIT/DELETE BUTTONS, which is being generated correctly, When I click the edit button  for a corresponding row, the HQ_NAME cell of that row should convert into a text box which would enable the HQ_NAME change. Or If the DELETE button is clicked the( i have ommited that code for the while) the row is deleted after the confirmation.